# How to prevent users from using Excel spreadsheet in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I would like to prevent normal users (not determined hackers) from copying an Excel spreadsheet to Google Sheets and then then using the Google version. I know I can't prevent users from copying the file, but I wonder if there are things I can do to make some features of the copied spreadsheet unusable with Google Sheets. I need a solution for this because my subscription mechanism depends on preventing the user from editing certain cells, and if the user copies the file to Google Sheets, he will be able to edit those cells (since Google Sheets does not respect Excel's cell protection).

I know that Google Sheets does not import Excel macros. So one approach might be to create macros (which I don't really need) and then tie some features to those macros, thus preventing the Google version from working. Or maybe I could use some obscure Excel function that Google doesn't support. Can anyone comment on these approaches or suggest other possibilities?

Comment: Tie the cells results to calculations using functions that don't work in google sheets... That way the results won't be there for them to use...

Comment: @PeterKleid Are you responsible for all users and all spreadsheets? Does a user need your permission to create a new Google spreadsheet or sheet? Are you running GSuite or the free Google Docs service? _I need a solution for this because my subscription mechanism depends on preventing the user from editing certain cells, and if the user copies the file to Google Sheets, he will be able to edit those cells (since Google Sheets does not respect Excel's cell protection)._ Would you please elaborate on this.

Comment: @Tedinoz  What I have developed is a financial planning spreadsheet that I will be selling to individuals.  Users will pay an annual subscription, and embedded in the Excel spreadsheet are formulas that validate the users subscription code and expiration date. Excel lets me protect and hide those cells so that users cannot manipulate them and, for example, extend their expiration date manually without actually paying for a subscription.  But when you open an Excel spreadsheet in Google Sheets any cell protection created in Excel is ignored and the user can see and change any hidden formulas.

Comment: You'd need to compare Excel V Google functions; the difference needn't be obscure, it could be a similar function that has a slightly different name (if there is such a thing).  Personally, I'd go VBA. Either 1) to do some important (or not) process or 2) re-create a standard Excel function and then use that "new" function in your spreadsheet. Just for the sake of discussion, you might recreate the `AVERAGE` function in VBA, call it something meaningless like, say, `WPREPG`, and then use `WPREPG` everywhere you would have used `AVERAGE`.

Comment: @PeterKleid FWIW, consider the possibility that the Excel security that you seek to rely upon _might be_ (or, more likely, IS) capable of being circumvented with tools &/or workarounds freely available on the net.

Comment: Thanks, Tedinoz. I will try your idea about recreating a forumula with VBA. Now if I can figure out how to mark your comment as the best response, I will do so.